# Python: get the string between two capitals

Tags: c++, python, string

I'd like your opinion as you might be more experienced on Python as I do.

I came from C++ and I'm still not used to the Pythonic way to do things.
I want to loop under a string, between 2 capital letters. For example, I could do that this way:

```
 i = 0
 str = "PythonIsFun"
 for i, z in enumerate(str):
     if(z.isupper()):
         small = ''
         x = i + 1
         while(not str[x].isupper()):
             small += str[x]
```

I wrote this on my phone, so I don't know if this even works but you caught the idea, I presume.
I need you to help me get the best results on this, not just in a non-forced way to the cpu but clean code too. Thank you very much

Comment: This will produce an infinite loop

Comment: Look at last while loop, it's endless. Probably, you should get to your computer before posting questions on SO?

Comment: Just to check, with an input like "PythonIsFun" are you looking for an output like "ythonsun" or something else? It isn't very clear.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those times when regexes are the best bet.

(And don't call a string `str`, by the way: it shadows the built-in function.)

```
s = 'PythonIsFun'
result = re.search('[A-Z]([a-z]+)[A-Z]', s)
if result is not None:
    print result.groups()[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use regular expressions:

```
import re
re.findall ( r'[A-Z]([^A-Z]+)[A-Z]', txt )
```

outputs `['ython']`, and

```
re.findall ( r'(?=[A-Z]([^A-Z]+)[A-Z])', txt )
```

outputs `['ython', 's']`; and if you just need the first match,

```
re.search ( r'[A-Z]([^A-Z]+)[A-Z]', txt ).group( 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to do this easily.

```
>>> s = "PythonIsFun"
>>> u = [i for i,x in enumerate(s) if x.isupper()]
>>> s[u[0]+1:u[1]]
'ython'
```

If you can't guarantee that there are two upper case characters you can check the length of `u` to make sure it is at least 2. This does iterate over the entire string, which could be a problem if the two upper case characters occur at the start of a lengthy string.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle this, but I'd use regular expressions.

This example will take "PythonIsFun" and return "ythonsun"

```
import re

text = "PythonIsFun"

pattern = re.compile(r'[a-z]')      #look for all lower-case characters

matches = re.findall(pattern, text) #returns a list of lower-chase characters

lower_string = ''.join(matches)     #turns the list into a string

print lower_string
```

outputs:

```
ythonsun
```